# Battery draining fast and Haptic feedback not working

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, haptic-feedback

I have a 13" MacBook Pro Retina early 2015. A few days ago I was working on a spreadsheet and then it suddenly crashed (black screen for several minutes). Once it finally started up again, the Haptic feedback had stopped working. After more use I have found that the battery is draining faster and when I close the lid from 100% charge over night, I come to it in the morning and it's well below 50% charge.

I believe I have reset the SMC, with no change. Updated the software to Mojave V10.14.

Has anyone else had this issue, or any ideas of a fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85064/discussion-on-question-by-jc247-battery-draining-fast-and-haptic-feedback-not-wo).

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution to a battery draining is that it's a faulty battery (which can even happen with a new part - it's less likely, but it does happen) or a faulty logic board.

The simple solution to haptic feedback is a bad logic board, a bad cable (connection reseat possibly) or a bad part.

So, right now you have two strikes against the logic board and can probably open and reconnect all cables before you start to replace parts to isolate this to one failure or two failures.

As far as software triage, you can test by downloading and installing a fresh, new OS onto an external USB drive. Even a slow drive will work for testing that the CPU is low in activity monitor and do a run time test to see how fast the battery discharges in idle and sleep. It also lets you test the haptic feedback on a fresh system. I'd hate for you to go in for more hardware repairs if there's a software cause.